# @OnClick on Butterknife doesn't work

Tags: android, butterknife

There is no error in code or gradle build but when I click to button, nothing happens

```
@BindView(R.id.bWakeup) Button bWakeup;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);


}

@OnClick(R.id.bWakeup)
public void wakeButtonClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetTimeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(MODE, WAKEUP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Did you specify the `ButterKnife` compiler in the gradle?

Comment: ofcourse I did.

Comment: Try cleaning your project and run again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited: Configuration is more simple now.**

I Followed below-given step and its working fine for me.

*Add the below Butter Knife dependencies:*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
          ...
        }
dependencies {
              compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
              annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
        }
```

If you are using Kotlin, replace annotationProcessor with kapt.

For more [refer](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)

Comment: Try adding           apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue. Turned out I didn't put `apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'` in my gradle

Answer (score 0):

For single button you will not get view object so just remove it and check

example

```
@OnClick(R.id.bWakeup)
public void onClick() {}
```